# Redirect based on Referral only once in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two redirect rules in htaccess for :
Rule 1.
User comes from domain1.com to main-domain.com redirect to main-domain.com/dir1/
Rule 2.
any request to main-domain.com/dir2/ --> redirect to --> somethingelese.com/something/

Individually Each rule working as aspected .
But Main problem is once after redirecting as per rule 1 from domain1.com to main-domain.com based on referral value of "domain1.com" , that referral value is not discarded , and for each next requests to main-domain.com it is redirecting only to main-domain.com/dir1/ . 
what I want is after redirecting only once based on referral that should be discarded. and shouldn't interfere on main-domain.com .

here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !dir1 http://main-domain.com/dir1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir2/.* [NC]
RewriteRule dir2/(.*) https://somethingelse.com/mfn/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**MORE:INFO :**
THe problem I found is Browsers are caching redirects . any workaround on this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !main-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^dir1 http://main-domain.com/dir1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir2(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule dir2(/(.*))? https://somethingelse.com/mfn$1 [R,L]
```

---

> **MORE:INFO** : THe problem I found is Browsers are caching redirects . any workaround on this ?

the problem here is probably status code 301 which means `Moved Permanently` and `This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise`. To avoid that use `302 Found`. More info on status codes [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

---

You can do it also from PHP (answering question from comment) :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match('/^.*domain1\.com/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) &&
    !preg_match('/main\-domain\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) &&
    !preg_match('/^\/dir1/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('Location: http://main-domain.com/dir1');
    exit(0);
}
if (preg_match('/^\/dir2/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('Location: https://somethingelse.com/mfn' . substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4));
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , this is not working . same redirection based on referrer !

Comment: Still the same problem even after R=302 ... the browser is caching the redirect .  I there any workground on this , using JS/PHP otherwise .?

Comment: I tested that htaccess above and for me it works. Maybe your browser has cached previous redirect (that 301) - remove cache and try again, 302 should not be cached. I changed R=302 to just R because 302 is default value.

Answer (score 0):

Before your rewrites, add a Vary header so that the browser knows that response may not be consistent, and not to cache it.

```
Header set Vary "*"
```

Comment: Ok I'll try , & will it require mod_deflate ?